# How do I record high-resolution (HD 1080p) video?

Tags: software-recommendation, hd-video, video-recording

I have a Logitech C910 USB 2.0 USB camera which supports up to 1080p video recording. I am using the camera on a laptop with a Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz CPU. Ubuntu 11.10 recognises the device and allows me to capture both photos and video.

What does not work is high-resolution video recording: I haven't had much luck with anything above VGA resolution. Cheese appears to be hard-coded to use OGG which puts way too much strain on the CPU. guvcview crashes whichever way I try it.

Is it possible to record smooth, 25fps video at 1280x720px+ resolutions on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Try guvcview:
http://guvcview.sourceforge.net/

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pj-assis/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install guvcview
```

Comment: HD resolution is 1920 x 1080 (which is stated for my web cam) but this option seems unavailable in `guvcview`.

Comment: For the standard 720p resolution (`1280x720`) this command line has worked for me: `guvcview --resolution=1280x720`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using guvcviewer, which is available directly in the [Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/guvcview/). Here is its [official website](http://guvcview.sourceforge.net/) with documentation, etc.